# javascript: How to stop ios app scroll top on focus input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am using cordova to develop a hybrid mobile application. It is working fine in android but in ios on focus of input text field the application is scrolling up and on clicking out the entire . application zooms in and comes back to normal size. this is my serious issue which am not able to solve.
request you to watch this video to clearly understand my issue: https://youtu.be/aLhADdaL_08
Please provide me a solution 
thanks

Comment: refer https://jmsliu.com/3461/set-uiwebview-content-not-to-scroll-when-keyboard-is-shown.html

Comment: I added the javascript content but still it is not working @SuryaSubenthiran

Comment: this is actually a bug. ios automatically tries to adjust the input whenever keyboard appears. There are some workaround to resolve this bug. like mentioned in the above link disabling the native webview scrolling. you will have to add native ios code to disable scrolling.

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran thank you bro.. i will try it but the problem is i dnt knw native code.. so looking for solution in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there here is a link to the config settings [config.xml Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/de/latest/config_ref/)

These two settings should help you out:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
```

place them somewhere inbetween your `<widget></widget>` tags.

Note that you have to rebuild your app if you change config files!

Comment: please watch this https://youtu.be/aLhADdaL_08 @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze